# How to manipulate arrays/index

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile

I would like to access the index of a list and concatenate it to the index of another list. For example, the first user's input is "AB" and the second is "CD", so when you press the button it should print "AD" (index 0 from first input + index 1 from second input). I'm getting this error: `RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0`. I've seen some solutions and many people say that the problem is in trying to access an array that is not ready yet, but I couldn't understand where to put this logic as well as the logic itself.

```
children: [
              TextField(
                controller: firstTextEditingController,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: 'Insert first input',
                  filled: true,
                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                ),
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              TextField(
                controller: secondTextEditingController,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: 'Insert second input',
                  filled: true,
                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                ),
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 55,
              ),
              ElevatedButton(
                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                    padding:
                        EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 50, vertical: 18)),
                onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => NextPage(
                      result: firstTextEditingController.text.length >0 ? firstTextEditingController.text[0] : '' +
                              secondTextEditingController.text.length > 0 ? secondTextEditingController.text[1] : ''),  
                  fullscreenDialog:
                      true,  com o input do user
                )),
                child: Text('Calculate'),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you share more of you code, like where are you declaring your text editing controllers and where are you assigning them to text fields

Answer (score 1):

That error means the value of `firstTextEditingController.text` is empty.
You can check whether you have bind it to a `textField`, and the `textField` has some text in it.

By the way, the `TextEditingController.text` is a String(not array).
and in dart, a string has operator `[]` like a List (array like).

Answer (score 0):

If you have two different TextEditingController() for two inputs, then you dont need array.
Because TextEditingController() text is a string and in your code you are

```
result: firstTextEditingController.text[0] +
        secondTextEditingController.text[1])
```

trying to access the first index of the both TextEditingController(), and if the text will empty it will throw error.

> RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0

This code will work in your case

```
result: firstTextEditingController.text.length >0 ? firstTextEditingController.text[0] : '' +
    secondTextEditingController.text.lenght > 0 ? secondTextEditingController.text[1] : '')
```

Complete Solution is this.

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

    void main() {
     runApp(MyApp());
   }

   class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
   @override
   

    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          title: 'Flutter Demo',
          theme: ThemeData(
            primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
          ),
          home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
        );
      }
    }

    class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
      MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
      final String title;
    
      @override
      _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
    }
    
    class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
      final firstTextEditingController = TextEditingController();
      final secondTextEditingController = TextEditingController();
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          body: Column(
            children: [
              TextField(
                controller: firstTextEditingController,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: 'Insert first input',
                  filled: true,
                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                ),
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              TextField(
                controller: secondTextEditingController,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: 'Insert second input',
                  filled: true,
                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                ),
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 55,
              ),
              ElevatedButton(
                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                    padding:
                    EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 50, vertical: 18)),
                onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => NextPage(
                        result: ((firstTextEditingController.text.length >0) ?firstTextEditingController.text[0] : '') +
                            ((secondTextEditingController.text.length > 0) ? secondTextEditingController.text[1] : '')),
                    // fullscreenDialog:
                    // true,  com o input do user
                )),
                child: Text('Calculate'),
              )
            ],
          ),
        );
      }
    
      NextPage({String result}) {}
    
    }
```

Comment: Hello @treadkhuram your solution does make sense to me but it's giving me an error inside secondTextEditingController: `The argument type 'int' can't be assigned to the parameter type String`

Comment: Wrap these line on code on brackets and error will be gone. result: ((firstTextEditingController.text.length >0) ?firstTextEditingController.text[0] : '') +
                        ((secondTextEditingController.text.length > 0) ? secondTextEditingController.text[1] : '')),